# How to get session in NextJS api route using with-iron-session?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using with-iron-session for authentication in my NextJS app however I'm not able to access the session cookie when I make API calls in my `getServerSideProps()` function. The API route is unable to get the session cookie used for authentication:

Session creation:

```
// this file is a wrapper with defaults to be used in both API routes and `getServerSideProps` functions
import { withIronSession } from "next-iron-session";

export default function withSession(handler) {
  return withIronSession(handler, {
    password: process.env.PASSWORD_HASH,
    cookieName: "MYCOOKIE",
    cookieOptions: {
      // the next line allows to use the session in non-https environements like
      // Next.js dev mode (http://localhost:3000)
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
      httpOnly: false,
    },
  });
}
```

My getServerSideProps call:

```
export const getServerSideProps = withSession(async ({ req, res }) => {
  const user = req.session.get("user");

  if (!user) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        permanent: false,
        destination: "/"
      },
      props: {}
    };
  }
  // I've replaced 'include' with 'same-origin' but it didn't make a difference
  const watchRes = await fetch('/watch',{credentials: 'include'});
  const watch = await watchRes.json();

  return{
    props: {
      user,
      watch
    }
  }
}
```

the api route:

```
// I've added await before the (req,res) but that was just guessing at this point
export default withSession((req, res) => {
    const user = req.session.get("user");
    if(user){
    
       res.send("Good");
    }else{
       res.status(403).end();
    }
}
```

While being logged in and I go to my `localhost/api/watch` route, it shows "Good" but when I try the fetch request I get the 403.

Comment: Keep in mind that `getServerSideProps` runs on the server-side (just like API routes) so rather than calling your internal API you should use the logic that's in your API route directly in `getServerSideProps`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add headers of the **getServerSideProps request** to the second call.

```
const headers = req.headers
const watchRes = await fetch('/watch',{headers});
```

in this way you have injected the cookies